# Make a box-shadow show over an adjacent floated element

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/YQ6PU/

Right now, `.link`'s background is above `.main`'s box-shadow. How do I make it underneath?

In other words, nothing in `.left` should be on top of the box-shadow.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add:

```
.link {
position: relative;
z-index: -10;
}
```

to the `.link` class

Comment: what do you mean slightly? it's pretty much what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/YQ6PU/2/

```
body {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1000px;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 1000px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.link {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #08C;
    position:relative;
z-index: -1;
}
```

@Perfect Dark said right!